# Can't use "az" to grant permissions to an app in Azure AD; getting a 403

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I’m trying to script adding a permission in Azure AD, and I’m getting a 403 for some reason.

Here’s the command:

```
az ad app permission grant --id 934b23f2-ab55-4876-83ce-b38e9966ea53 --api  2ac352a9-b35a-4db8-bbce-84d9245faa45
```

Here’s the debug output:

```
msrest.http_logger : Request URL: 'https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6'
msrest.http_logger : Request method: 'POST'
msrest.http_logger : Request headers:
msrest.http_logger :     'Accept': 'application/json'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
msrest.http_logger :     'accept-language': 'en-US'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Length': '323'
msrest.http_logger :     'User-Agent': 'python/3.6.6 (Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0) msrest/0.6.6 msrest_azure/0.6.0 azure-graphrbac/0.60.0 Azure-SDK-For-Python AZURECLI/2.0.62'
msrest.http_logger : Request body:
msrest.http_logger : {"odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.OAuth2PermissionGrant", "clientId": "874bf2e7-d191-4d86-ba64-234c885c703a", "consentType": "AllPrincipals", "resourceId": "e7c4266c-e7c0-440f-910a-2557f24b842c", "scope": "user_impersonation", "startTime": "2019-04-18T00:11:56.102063", "expiryTime": "2020-04-18T00:11:56.102063"}
msrest.universal_http : Configuring redirects: allow=True, max=30
msrest.universal_http : Configuring request: timeout=100, verify=True, cert=None
msrest.universal_http : Configuring proxies: ''
msrest.universal_http : Evaluate proxies against ENV settings: True
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): graph.windows.net:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://graph.windows.net:443 "POST /72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1" 403 219
msrest.http_logger : Response status: 403
msrest.http_logger : Response headers:
msrest.http_logger :     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
msrest.http_logger :     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8'
msrest.http_logger :     'Expires': '-1'
msrest.http_logger :     'ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name': 'flQBgrwiZdgfrwyQn7i7mb8tOHe8Zm56rla4LDh9+Zw='
msrest.http_logger :     'request-id': 'e514bba2-7cc9-47e7-bd16-ff1ea17fbad8'
msrest.http_logger :     'client-request-id': '924eb878-616e-11e9-8077-f26e0bc197ab'
msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version': '1.6'
msrest.http_logger :     'ocp-aad-session-key': '-RrCLfYgOSFwqxz4IBLGEBFBrYfXBZbU8zNwiCGag-dWYfm6EGWjClVXFX9LjmWphFkDKZaqQP39ko2PuX_K4DXuqK1NwUB5wayM8e5wnXvaSoYQW1B4nwJDR7JAHnwU.e2QPHdU1fQSwX4_tnWM81ajF8thbjmTeEPBE9HPtOJI'
msrest.http_logger :     'DataServiceVersion': '3.0;'
msrest.http_logger :     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
msrest.http_logger :     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
msrest.http_logger :     'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319'
msrest.http_logger :     'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET'
msrest.http_logger :     'Duration': '545850'
msrest.http_logger :     'Date': 'Thu, 18 Apr 2019 00:11:55 GMT'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Length': '219'
msrest.http_logger : Response content:
msrest.http_logger : {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"e514bba2-7cc9-47e7-bd16-ff1ea17fbad8","date":"2019-04-18T00:11:56"}}
msrest.exceptions : Operation failed with status: 'Forbidden'. Details: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6
cli.azure.cli.core.util : Operation failed with status: 'Forbidden'. Details: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6
Operation failed with status: 'Forbidden'. Details: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6
az_command_data_logger : exit code: 1
telemetry.save : Save telemetry record of length 2468 in cache
telemetry.check : Negative: The C:\Users\mikebaz\.azure\telemetry.txt was modified at 2019-04-17 20:04:03.430973, which in less than 600.000000 s
command ran in 2.421 seconds.
```

And this is what I’m trying to grant:

```
[
  {
    "additionalProperties": null,
    "expiryTime": "",
    "resourceAccess": [
      {
        "additionalProperties": null,
        "id": "4b7cb559-04e7-4d6e-8b59-362ceccc6a89",
        "type": "Scope"
      }
    ],
    "resourceAppId": "2ac352a9-b35a-4db8-bbce-84d9245faa45"
  }
]
```

I can successfully do the grant in the Portal (that’s how I can get the grant details above), so I know I am allowed to do the grant.

Any thoughts about what I’m missing here?

Answer (score 2):

At least one issue that I notice is that value for `--api` parameter in your command is probably not correct.

In Json that you mention is the working copy from Portal, `resourceAppId` is `2ac352a9-b35a-4db8-bbce-84d9245faa45` so that should be the value of `--api` parameter or target API in your command.

```
[
  {
    "additionalProperties": null,
    "expiryTime": "",
    "resourceAccess": [
      {
        "additionalProperties": null,
        "id": "4b7cb559-04e7-4d6e-8b59-362ceccc6a89",
        "type": "Scope"
      }
    ],
    "resourceAppId": "2ac352a9-b35a-4db8-bbce-84d9245faa45"
  }
]
```

Also make sure that you have the `934b23f2-ab55-4876-83ce-b38e9966ea53` is the applicationid or objectid for your application.

```
az ad app permission grant --id 934b23f2-ab55-4876-83ce-b38e9966ea53 --api 2ac352a9-b35a-4db8-bbce-84d9245faa45 --scope user_impersonation --consent-type AllPrincipals
```

Comment: ah I missed the API ID being wrong, that was dumb - it's still not working through so I'm going to edit the question.  I'm upvoting your answer because it helped get me closer and want you to get some credit, but it's not working yet.

Comment: ok makes sense. Two suggestions **1)** You can specify the exact scope id for `--scope` parameter, i.e. `4b7cb559-04e7-4d6e-8b59-362ceccc6a89`. **2)** I hope you aren't doing this from the `Try it` experience in browser on the documentation page, because I got the same error.. 403 forbidden when trying that even though all parameters were correct and signed in user was global admin.. but the same command works fine when running it locally from my system.

Comment: re: `Try it`, no, doing it from a local prompt, all good there :)  re: adding the scope, doesn't seem to change anything.  You mentioned being signed in as a global admin - I'm not a global admin but I have delegated permissions, enough that the portal works - but I wonder if it's possible that `az` doesn't handle that right?  feels weird to assume that though.

Comment: ok.. I think `az` command should be able to work with same permissions as Portal.. I didn't quite follow the part where you say you have delegated permissions, because you're trying to do consent for all users in org.. notice the `--consent-type AllPrincipals` in your command. If you want to do consent for only a specific user then you will need to use `--consent-type Principal` and also specify the `--principal-id` parameter.. If it still doesn't makes sense, please describe the steps you did in portal as that would help me understand whether you're doing the same thing with command or not..